# Swift different types of generics in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics

So I'm creating some view models for UITableView. The table has different cell types, so I used generics, but there were some problems when putting them into arrays.

First I defined a struct:

```
private struct Section<E, C> where C: UITableViewCell {
    let cell: C.Type
    let rows: [E]
    let configure: (_ row: E, _ cell: inout C, _ index: Int) -> Void
}
```

then I declared an array:

```
private lazy var sections: [Any] = [
    Section(cell: TextFieldTableViewCell.self,
            rows: [
              TableRow(image: R.image.home.device.settings.name(),
                       title: R.string.localizable.deviceSettingsViewControllerElementDeviceName(),
                       content: device.name,
                       action: { _ in

              }),
              TableRow(image: R.image.home.device.settings.location(),
                       title: R.string.localizable.deviceSettingsViewControllerElementDeviceLocation(),
                       content: device.location,
                       action: { _ in

              })],
            configure: { row, cell, index in
    }),
    Section(cell: DeviceSettingsNightVisionTableViewCell.self,
            rows: [
              TableRow(image: R.image.home.device.settings.nightVision(),
                       title: R.string.localizable.deviceSettingsViewControllerElementNightVision(),
                       content: 0,
                       action: { _ in
              })],
            configure: { row, cell, index in
    })
  ]
```

The problems are:

1. I can't specify the type of array because they are actually different generics.
2. If I use `[Any]` as the type of the array, then every time I take an element, I have to convert it to the corresponding type, which is inconsistent with my original design.
3. I did some searching and realized that I might need to use a protocol to solve the problem, but I tried many times and failed.

The result I expect is that when I take an element, I can get its type correctly without conversion.

My current approach is like:

in `numberOfRowsInSection:`,

```
switch section {
        case 0:
          return (self.sections[section] as! Section<TableRow, TextFieldTableViewCell>).rows.count
        case 1:
          return (self.sections[section] as! Section<TableRow, DeviceSettingsNightVisionTableViewCell>).rows.count
        default:
          return 0
        }
```

It is obviously not elegant enough, I would like to ask if there is a better solution, any help or advice is very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use protocol for your row object, and use identifier instead of type, I'm not totally sure this will fix your problem completely but you can try it:

```
protocol CellProtocol where Self: UITableViewCell {
    func bind(_ object: RowProtocol)
}

protocol RowProtocol {

}

struct Row1: RowProtocol {

}

struct Row2: RowProtocol {

}

private struct Section {
    let cellIdentifier: String
    let rows: [RowProtocol]
    let configure: (_ row: RowProtocol, _ cell: inout UITableViewCell, _ index: Int) -> Void


}

private lazy var sections: [Section] = [
    Section(cellIdentifier: "cell1",
            rows: [Row1()],
            configure: { row, cell, index in
    }),
    Section(cellIdentifier: "cell2",
            rows: [Row2()],
            configure: { row, cell, index in
    })
]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: sections[indexPath.section].cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CellProtocol {
        cell.bind(sections[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Let your custom cell class to conform to `CellProtocol`, then inside there `bind` function, try to convert the `RowProtocol` into `Row1` or `Row2` to get their values.

Also Im not sure how you are going to configure inside that sections object, it feels off, I rather let the cell class to handle configuration itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I realize that there is no perfect solution to this problem. So I changed my mind and borrowed the design from [Section](https://github.com/venmo/Static).